# How can I change the hinge side on an LG LBN10551PV refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, hinges

I have an LG LBN10551PV apartment fridge. I ordered it with the door hinge on the wrong side (left) and would like to put it on the right. The instruction manual describes how to do this, and I've gotten to the final step, which is to attach the top hinge:

> Then install the upper hinge (27) supplied in the refrigerator package placing the dowel into the appropriate upper hole in the door of the refrigeration compartment (A).

The top hinge plate clearly has a left and right hand version, and (short of flipping it over in the fourth dimension) there's no way of making it work on the other side. Here's what I have: [image: Left-hand hinge]
and here's what I need (the following is a dramatization):
[image: right-hand hinge].

(I had Sears deliver it and they didn't include extras from the packaging. I've checked through and behind all of the freezer drawers and all of the compartments within the fridge and there's nothing there.)

Both LG customer support and Sears Parts Direct are telling me that I can just use the existing top hinge, but I've tried everything I can think of to make it work and it just won't. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Photos would help here if you could add some.

Comment: can you flip the top and bottom ones.  I.e. left side top becomes right side bottom?

Comment: The middle and bottom hinges do get flipped, but they wouldn't work in the top position.

Answer (score 4):

I called LG electronics at 1 (800) 243-0000 and went through the phone tree to the parts department. I was connected to their West Coast (US) distributor and finally got a call back. The part is on its way.

The moral of the story is the parts distributor knows more about the fridge than the email support person at LG.